# Cannot play DVDs on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vlc, dvd

I've got libdvdcss2 installed but still no joy. Tried VLC, mplayer and the default players and all give me errors. Regionset does not even see the DVD.

`vlc /dev/sr0`:

```
VLC media player 2.1.4 Rincewind (revision 2.1.4-0-g2a072be)
[0x862118] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 4.2.1
libdvdnav: DVD Title: NAUSICAA
libdvdnav: DVD Serial Number: 43053257___MVB__
libdvdnav: DVD Title (Alternative): 
libdvdnav: Unable to find map file '/home/alex/.dvdnav/NAUSICAA.map'
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x00000153
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x000001ba
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x0000c924
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_0.VOB at 0x0000d2a0
libdvdread: Elapsed time 1
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x0000d2ed
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_0.VOB at 0x0000eea8
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x0000eef5
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_0.VOB at 0x0000fb30
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x0000fb7d
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_0.VOB at 0x00017aba
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x00017b07
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_0.VOB at 0x0035ebfb
libdvdread: Elapsed time 1
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x0035ec48
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_0.VOB at 0x0037dd38
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_1.VOB at 0x0037dd85
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_0.VOB at 0x003df255
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_1.VOB at 0x003df2a2
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 8 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 2
[0x7f8c140009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7f8c140009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7f8c140009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
[0x7f8c140009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
```

Answer (score 6):

VLC is able to ignore the region value with most drives. However, it must be set to *some*thing:

```
sudo apt-get install regionset
```

Place the DVD in your drive and in your case, run:

```
regionset /dev/sr0
```

Then set the Region from 1 to 8:
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code#Region_codes_and_countries

Comment: regionset does not require sudo but does require a readable disk of any sort in the drive when run

Answer (score 0):

I kinda face this issue too, the thing is I have `regionset` installed but it doesn't work for me as I have an older DVD-rom and all limits to change the region code has been emptied. So as you know or don't there's a software called AnyDVD HD that is popular on Windows but AnyDVD HD has its alternative on Linux World as it uses decryptor like `makemkv` which makes it possible to play original discs without changing a region code! I tested it on one of my DVDs bought within U.S. territory and it works like a charm on any video player. To install it run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/makemkv-beta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install makemkv-bin makemkv-oss
```

Type in Dash `makemkv` and launch it now navigate to Help --> Register and enter this key:

```
T-5gyrR7NzjlT9R4WwnwovJ591eN3s_IGkp51GQAJn0FDNQWat4uif8H_sJ6IoZN2Wv2
```

Now restart the program and insert the DVD and wait until the `makemkv` loads it. When it's loaded play it with any Video Player.

[image]

One thing this is not free software if you like it you can buy it but it's also available using beta keys from [this source](http://www.makemkv.com/forum2/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1053) as it's stated the new keys will be added.

Answer (score 0):

1. install all the above.
2. install the QUICKTIME files.
   this should enable you to play the dvd.
   if you get an error about blocks, likely your drive is faulty.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that you have installed the following package:

`ubuntu-restricted-extras`

It is set of many multimedia related packages, including the libdvdnav, which is probably missing in your case. If you have `vlc` and `libdvdcss` already, then you have everything required to play any DVD movie.

Comment: doesn't he need to install dvdread4 and its counterpart idon'trememberthenameofit?

Comment: No, I am not wrong nor forgotten anything. OP has both VLC and libdvdcss already installed - please read the question carefully. The script install-css.sh is not a part of the libdvdread setup. It just downloads and install libdvdcss package since it is not available in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I've got it installed, but dvds still do not play.