# Unable to play commercial DVDs

Tags: software-recommendation, dvd

I recently wanted to play a commercial DVD in my computer's built in DVD drive. So I the inserted Faulty Towers DVD into my DVD drive, and then told it to launch it in `Videos`, and it just gave me this:

[image: Install extra multimedia plugins]

But I remember that when I tried to install these plugins in the past, even though the installation was successful, the DVD still does not play. I have already looked at this question and its answers, and they do not help: [Why does my optical drive not play commercial dvds?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247502/why-does-my-optical-drive-not-play-commercial-dvds)

I know that there is some software which somebody once told me about which allows you to play commercial DVDs on Ubuntu, but I cannot remember the name. So does anybody know either the name of this software, or another way round this issue?

---

### OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my optical drive not play commercial dvds?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247502/why-does-my-optical-drive-not-play-commercial-dvds)

Comment: @Pilot6: No it's not! As I said in my question, that did not help me, so there's no point in closing it as duplicate!

Comment: Sry for that, but that's all that unblocks encrypted disks. Did you install ubuntu-restricted-extras? There are some more codecs, supporting encryption too.

Comment: @Pilot6: I've tried that already, but it did not work.

Comment: if the CD/DVD has CSS Protection or whatever check my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/501277/cannot-play-dvds-on-ubuntu-14-04/622474#622474) maybe it be useful for you ;)

Comment: @Mateo: No, sorry, I meant DVDs.

Comment: @JoKeR: Nope, sorry, but that didn't help.

Comment: MakeMKV should've worked I tried lots of different DVDs with different protections and played them with SMPlayer without problems. Maybe there's smth else in your issue.

Comment: Is your region set correctly (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Setting_DVD_Region_Codes) ?

Comment: @NGRhodes: Ahh! No, it wasn't, that fixed it! Thanks! Could you please convert that into an answer so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Install Gstreamer libraries as `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing to check is that your region is set correctly on your DVD drive.
From [Setting DVD Region Codes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Setting_DVD_Region_Codes):

> If your DVD player regularly locks up when you try to play back a DVD,
>   your DVD player probably does not match the DVD's [region code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_lockout).
>   Region codes are a form of vendor lock-in. For example, you cannot
>   play a DVD published in Japan (Region 2) on a DVD player in the United
>   States (Region 1) without changing the region code of the DVD player
>   (unless you own a region-free DVD player). You can view or modify the
>   region code of your DVD drive with the [regionset](http://linvdr.org/projects/regionset/) tool.

You can install the regionset utility from universe with the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get install regionset
```

Then to set the region, insert a DVD from the region you want to use and run the following command (replace `sr0` with the name of your DVD drive if different):

```
sudo regionset /dev/sr0
```

**Note there is a 5 change limit** (usually).
Also note most players will ignore the region set (and some drives come without any set region). 
Further details see [Setting DVD Region Codes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs#Setting_DVD_Region_Codes).

Comment: Why is there a limit of how many times you can change it? And is there any way to circumvent this limit?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to do to play DVDs in Ubuntu.  First you need to install restricted extras:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Next you need to install libdvdread:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

Finally you need to execute it:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Some Media Players won't automatically update with the ability to play DVDs. I would recommend installing VLC (if you haven't already), and using it to watch DVDs.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```