# Can not play DVD in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dvd, gstreamer

While inserting a **DVD** (which plays well in a DVD player) into my laptop, a message appears, requesting me to install **`gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`**.

What is this? How can I solve this problem and watch my DVD?

Comment: Do you installed it ?

Comment: On what are you playing the DVD? is it Rhythmbox?

Comment: @ AzkerM no its videos player in ubuntu

Comment: See if this is any help? http://askubuntu.com/a/628113/179042

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned package `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` is a package containing codecs needed to decode and play DVD video content. Here is its description:

> Description-en: GStreamer plugins from the "bad" set

> GStreamer is a streaming media framework, based on graphs of filters
> which operate on media data.  Applications using this library can do
> anything from real-time sound processing to playing videos, and just
> about anything else media-related.  Its plugin-based architecture means
> that new data types or processing capabilities can be added simply by
> installing new plug-ins.

> GStreamer Bad Plug-ins is a set of plug-ins that aren't up to par compared
> to the rest. They might be close to being good quality, but they're missing
> something - be it a good code review, some documentation, a set of tests, a
> real live maintainer, or some actual wide use.

It is not installed by default in Ubuntu, because it contains proprietary or non-freely licensed codecs. You may still use them legally, but the Ubuntu developers preferred to only ship open-source software with the default installation.

The following command typed in a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) should solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Alternatively, click the red button below which will take you to a site that helps you installing the package through your Software Center.
However, I strongly recommend using the terminal, because the other method might lead to problems because the Software Center fails to display you the License Agreement.

[image: Install via the software center]

---

If you want, you can probably also just install the requested [gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad) [image: Install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad] codec package only (not tested by me, I can't guarantee that this will work):

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
```

Comment: well, by following these instruction , i see that it consumes **341 MB** of data . is it a such type of huge software ?? is there any other way to play dvd inspite of this ??

Comment: You can also probably only install the requested `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` package alone: run `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` in a terminal window instead.

Comment: @Bapi : When you decide to install only the gstreamer codecs, you might want to consider installing gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly additionally. :)